# SQS Message with Number MessageAttribute not received by Spring JMS Listener

Tags: spring-boot, jms, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

Below is my setup:

- AWS SNS Topic
- AWS SQS Queue subscribed to the topic with 'Raw Message Delivery' enabled
- Spring boot application with `JmsListener` listening on SQS queue

Versions:

- amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib 1.0.4
- spring-boot 1.4.2.RELEASE
- spring-jms: 4.3.4.RELEASE
- spring-cloud: 1.1.8.RELEASE

When I publish a message to SNS Topic (through AWS console) with `Number` MessageAttribute, it reaches SQS. However, my JMS Listener code does not receive the message - i.e. the code does not get triggered at all when a message with `Number` MessageAttribute is received from SQS.

Sample:

1. SQS message received without `Number` MessageAttribute ==> triggers `JmsListener`

[image]

2. SQS message received with `Number` MessageAttribute ==> does **NOT** trigger `JmsListener`

[image]
Code:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "sqs.queue.name")
public void processAccountMessage(TextMessage msg) throws JMSException {
    logger.info("msg: {}", msg);
}
```

and `JmsListenerContainerFactory` code as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MessageConfig {

@Inject
private ClientFactory<AmazonSQS> sqsClientFactory;

@Value("${aws.region}")
private String awsRegion;

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws Exception {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory =
                new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(), this.sqsClientFactory.getClient(AmazonSQS.class, this.awsRegion)));
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
        factory.setConcurrency("1");
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: I can't validate right now but could it be related to the argument of `processAccountMessage` that expects a `TextMessage`?

Comment: I changed it to `Message` and it had the same behaviour. Which type do you believe may work there?